# ORA-28500 from dblink oracle UUID

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, dblink

I get an error when I call select from dblink SQL Server to Oracle

```
SELECT UUID FROM TABLE@MSSQL_DBLINK;
```

> ```
> [Error] Execution (1: 1): 
>  ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:  
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Numeric value out of range {22003}  
>  ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from MSSQL_DBLINK
> ```

How do I convert a `UUID` to a `VARCHAR` or is there another way?

Comment: what happens if you try: select cast(uuid) as string_uuid from ...

Comment: [Error] Execution (3: 30): ORA-28500: connection from ORACLE to a non-Oracle system returned this message:
[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Numeric value out of range {22003}
ORA-02063: preceding 2 lines from MSSQL_DBLINK